# Trying to prevent numbers repeating (Java/NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, numbers, repeat

I'm a student learning Java (and working with NetBeans at school).
We are trying to do a simple Bingo program (bingo boards with 15 numbers in them that aren't repeated)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j = j + 2) {
            aux = r.nextInt(90) + 1;
            while (sacados[aux] == aux) {
                aux = r.nextInt(90) + 1;
            }
            sacados[aux] = aux;
            carton[i][j] = aux;
        }
    }
```

I don't know if this code is a good solution (this little code is what I have wrote for chosing 15 different numbers). I've tried, and it didn't showed me any repeated numbers, but maybe it will be a coincidence.
Just in case, we aren't alowed to use "ArrayList" or some advanced functions, because we didn't learned them yet in class.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:

```
public static void jugar(int[][] carton) {
    /**
     * Módulo que permite introducir datos en variables *
     */
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    /**
     * Módulo para utilizar la función "random" *
     */
    Random r = new Random();
    int aux;
    /**
     * Variable boolean que ayuda a comprobar que el número está en el
     * cartón previamente o no *
     */
    boolean seguir = true;
    /**
     * Array que almacena los números del cartón temporalmente para
     * comprobar que no se repiten *
     */
    int[] sacados = new int[91];
    /**
     * Array en la que almacenamos los numeros premiados con antelación *
     */
    int[] ganadores = new int[15];
    /**
     * Indice para array de ganadores *
     */
    int z = 0;
    /**
     * Variable que hace de contador para determinar bingo *
     */
    int contador = 0;
    /** Variable para seguir (s/n) **/
    char seguirl;
    /**
     * Guardamos los números ganadores en una array diferente para
     * mostrarlos al ganar *
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j = j + 2) {
            ganadores[z] = carton[i][j];
            z++;
        }
    }

    while (contador != 15) {
        if (seguir==true){
        /** Si el número se repite, no seguirá y volverá a sacar otro número distinto **/
        do {
            aux = r.nextInt(90) + 1;
        } while (sacados[aux] == aux);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j = j + 2) {
                if (aux == carton[i][j]) {
                    carton[i][j] = -1;
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                System.out.print(carton[i][j] + "  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Nuevo número: " + aux);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("¿Siguiente número (s/n)?:");
        seguirl = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (seguirl == 115){
            seguir = true;
        }else{
            seguir = false;
        }

        }else{
            System.out.println("Partida abortada.");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }System.out.println("BINGO!!!");
    System.out.println("Los números premiados de esta tanda han sido:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        System.out.print(ganadores[i]+" ");

    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Y todos los que han salido");
    for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
        if (sacados[i]!=0){
        System.out.print(ganadores[i]+" ");
        }           
    }
    System.out.println("Fin de partida.");
    System.exit(0);

}
```

Here is the method that works as the bingo itself.

Comment: `Random` is not the correct approach. How does bingo work? You don't create random numbers - you pull random numbers **once** from a bag that contains all the numbers.  Therefore you want an array that contains all possible numbers and to randomly draw from it. The simplest solution is to create an array `[1..15]` then do a [Fisher -Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: It should work, but you didn't share the declaration of `sacados`, if you made it `int [90]` by mistake you may encounter problems. Also, it would probably be better if it was an array of booleans.

Comment: I've made an array int of [91] for not having problems. Also, i've added to the main post the code that do bingo's stuff.

Comment: BTW, are you sure about your Bingo board size? Standard Bingo is 5x5 with an empty middle square, giving you 24 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any built in functions you can do

```
int[] balls = new int[90];
for(int i = 0; i < 90; i++) balls[i] = i + 1;
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
   // select an unused ball at random.
   // the number of balls which haven't been used is 90 - i.
   int select = rand.nextInt(90 - i);
   int number = balls[select];
   System.out.println(number);
   // remove the ball from the available array
   balls[select] = balls[90 - i];
}
```

This is more efficient as it never selects a ball which hasn't been used already.  This can make a big difference when there is few balls left.

---

It is worth remembering that the numbers are not entirely random, they have to be selected from the numbers you haven't used before.  A simpler way to do this is to generate every possible number and shuffle them. Like a deck of cards being shuffled and a container of balls being arranged randomly.

e.g.

```
List<Integer> allBalls = IntStream.range(1, 91).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(allBalls);
List<Integer fifteenBalls = allBalls.subList(0, 15);
```

This will leave you with 15 balls, chosen at random, without duplicates.

Comment: But the OP said that he must not use anything like `ArrayList` or advanced functions.

Comment: @Tchangla  This doesn't stop you doing the same thing, but without those classes. All the source is accessible ;)

Comment: @Tchangla I assume you know how to fill an array with the values 1 to 90, and to print just 15 of them.  The shuffle is a loop of about 4-5 lines of code.  You could optimise the code to only shuffle 15 of them and stop when you have enough.